# How can i optimize this code

Tags: vb.net

Using inventor Ilogic (Based on VB), i want to slect a Excel cell based upon the drawing name.
so when the drawing name ends on 0001 it should take cell B1.
when the drawing name ends on 0002 its hould take cell B2, and so on.

this is the code as i have it now, but is i need to expand this to aprox 50, this should be able to be dont in a cleaner way:

```
Select Case name
Case "62-31-SD-0001"
    Parameter("31-W00.ipt.MP_Length") = GoExcel.CellValue("31-W00.xls", "Blad1", "B1")
Case "62-31-SD-0002"    
    Parameter("31-W00.ipt.MP_Length") = GoExcel.CellValue("31-W00.xls", "Blad1", "B2")
Case "62-31-SD-0003"
    Parameter("31-W00.ipt.MP_Length") = GoExcel.CellValue("31-W00.xls", "Blad1", "B3")
Case "62-31-SD-0004"    
    Parameter("31-W00.ipt.MP_Length") = GoExcel.CellValue("31-W00.xls", "Blad1", "B4")
End Select
```

Anyone can help me on how to do this in a more effective way ?

Comment: I am not sure if it is typo, but this specific situation cannot easily be extrapolated (to 50): the last case represents an exception to the behaviour shown in the 3 previous ones (0004 -> B5)

Comment: @varocarbas, I hope it is a typo in the code, if not then the only easy way is to make a dictionary with pre-populated value

Comment: Ah yea sorry a typo, fixed in the example now. Thanx for pointing out

Comment: @Fredou Actually, when I firstly saw this problem, my intention was writing an answer accounting for this behaviour (1-3 and 5 different); but I saw your answers and the 50 cases more bit and assumed that it was a typo (asked just to make sure). BTW, I was the one +1-ing you and Plutonix to compensate (all the three answers were equivalently valid; even the spydon one was wrong, not only because what you said, also he was using a weird "Right" function, but was the only one who got a +1!, so it didn't sound too fair) :)

Comment: @varocarbas, I think microsoft should "start" marking these methods obsolete (warning, not error), these exists mostly for vba/vb6 compatibility. in the end, it work and this is the real goal :-) looking at this right method with ilspy make me smile

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that right was an unencouraged method to use, I don't code VB, I just googled some string functions. It could easily be replaced by Substring. And I've fixed the code to not naively remove all zeros like I did in the beginning. I was very tired at that point. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it as simple as this if I have understood your question correctly:

```
Parameter("31-W00.ipt.MP_Length") = 
    GoExcel.CellValue("31-W00.xls", "Blad1", "B"&Integer.Parse(Right(name, 4)))
```

It first takes the four last characters from name and then removes the 0's in the beginning of the number from it and then finally concatenates it with B.

Comment: blindly removing zero is bad in the scenario, it will break if you have 62-31-SD-0010, the last 0 will be removed

Comment: @Fredou Thank you, fixed it accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

something like this should simplify the case

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Parameter(""31-W00.ipt.MP_Length"") = GoExcel.CellValue(""31-W00.xls"", ""Blad1"", ""B{0}"")", B_Something("62-31-SD-0004"))
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Public Function B_Something(ByVal something As String) As String
    Return Integer.Parse(something.Substring(something.Length - 4)).ToString

    'or
    'Return something.Substring(something.Length - 4).TrimStart(New Char() {"0"c})
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Dictionary or List of a XLParms Class which stores the string values, then

```
  Private myCol as New Dictionary(of String, XLParms)

   For each kvp as KeyValuePair in myCol
     Parameter(kvp.Value.Parameter) = _
          GoExcel.CellValue(kvp.Value.XLFile, _
            kvp.Value.Something, kvp.Value.XLCell)
  Next kvp
```

As a list, just use it in a for/next loop.  It depends on whether you sometimes need only some of these things (then use a dictionary to pull out the ones you want by ParamerName) or not. The List/Dictionary values themselves can be serialized or saved so that you dont have code populating all of them in code.